# How to show the image only but the rest hide first and show?

Tags: javascript

Was able to hide the rest and show when clicked the about and size but I want the image to show first when the webpage opens. In my code, the image only opens when I click them. Here's my code:

```
<div class="col- menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" onclick="toggleStuff('pic1'); return false;">Picture</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onclick="toggleStuff('description'); return false;">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onclick="toggleStuff('size'); return false;">Size</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <p><span id="pic1" style="display: none;"><img src="1.jpg"></span></p>
        <p><span id="description" style="display: none;">Cool!</span></p>
        <p><span id="size" style="display: none;"><img src="2.jpg"></span></p>
      </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleStuff(id) {
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'block') {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the *style="display:none";*

```
<p><span id="pic1"><img src="1.jpg"></span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. May I ask what will I add to my code when I click the other buttons, the opened element automatically closes?